# Transit Visa in Germany for Indian citizen with Polish TRC application stamp

Tags: indian-citizens, germany, transit-visas

I am an Indian national staying in Poland on Polish National Visa. I have applied for the Polish Temporary Resident Card (TRC) in September 2019 and have received stamp on my passport legalizing my stay in Poland. Decision on my resident card has not been made yet and my current Visa will expire soon.

However, I have to urgently travel back to my home country for some work. I have booked a Lufthansa flight to India (from Warsaw) which transits through the Munich airport.

As my visa will be expired before my intended travel date and my TRC application is still in progress,  can I pass through Munich with TRC application stamp in my passport? Or do I need to obtain transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving answer here for any future readers (if any).

I got in touch with Border control in Munich Airport. According to them, I **cannot** transit through Germany if I do not have either Schengen Visa or Temporary Resident Card.

With my current situation, I can directly go from Poland to India but I cannot transit through any other Schengen area without valid visa. So my current option is to either cancel current ticket or get German Transit Visa.

Comment: The Embassy site confirms that for a visit or transit a **Karta pobytu** is needed. Also: **The Warsaw Embassy generally does not issue a Schengen visa.** [German Embassy Warsaw](https://polen.diplo.de/pl-de/03-service/03-01-visainformationen-de/visum-brauche/490700?openAccordionId=item-486624-1-panel)